# Flutter - How to return a value from function to a variable

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am trying to retrieve a UID from Firebase and return it to a variable. However I am unable to get it working. Could someone please help on this. Thanks

```
getUID() async {
    final userId = await widget.auth.getCurrentUser();
    print('checking user id ${userId.uid}');
    return userId.uid;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  void foo() async {
    final userID = await getUID();
    print("UID is ${userID}");
  }
  foo();
  print("UID is ${userID}");
}
```

Comment: Define "unable to get it working", what errors are you getting? What line do these errors occur? What happens when you inspect using a debugger?

Comment: Apologies. When I try to print it as showin in the last line it says as userID is undefined. I need to get the value outside from foo function to pass on to other pages.

Comment: please add code of getcurrentuser

Comment: This is the code of getCurrentUser from auth.dart file

  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }

Comment: Asnwered  , comment if something goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). You declare `userId` within the inner function `foo`, so that variable doesn't exist outside of `foo`. If you want to access it within the scope of `initState`, you need to declare it within that scope:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  String userId;

  void foo() async {
    userID = await getUID();
    print("UID is ${userID}");
  }

  foo();
  print("UID is ${userID}");
}
```

Comment: After invoking the foo() function and trying to print it shows as "UID is null". Although inside the foo function the value gets print, but not able to get it outside.

Comment: @RaghuCK The issue is that `foo` is marked as `async`, but when you call `foo`, you don't `await` it. This causes `initState` to just breeze past it without waiting for the results. Normally I'd say just make `initState` asynchronous, but in this case, Flutter will not allow you to do that because all `async` functions return `Future` and `initState` must return `void`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help how to get the userID value into a variable so I can pass on to other pages. Or else please let me know how to get the uid of a user from firebase.

Comment: @RaghuCK Put it in a separate function that you _can_ mark as `async`. Then you can `await` on `foo` and set the result to a variable all you want. Although in this situation, `foo` _is_ the separate function and the userID is really coming from `getUID`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this Outside every Class

```
String getCurrentUser(){
return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
}
```

and the class in which you are using it should be

```
class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _RootPageState();
}
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
String _userId;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_userId=getCurrentUser();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Text(_userId==null?"NO User Logged In":_userId);
}
```

Also note with latest version of firebaseauth this function no longer returns a future;

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Create a String variable to hold the value of the user UID
String userId; 

void getCurrentUser() {
try {
  User loggedInUser = _auth.currentUser;
  if (loggedInUser != null) {
    userId = loggedInUser.uid;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

}

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getCurrentUser(); // The code to get the currrent user is run in the initState and user UID stored in the 'userId' variable

}
```

You now have access to the currently logged in user UID anywhere in your current Class.